# How to make a single page website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

when i was browsing I found a website that using single page only but using different background each navigation...I'm just a new web programmer does anyone know a good basic tutorial to learn this stuff? I wanna build a website that uses single help me please.

http://mypizzaoven.nl/#data-home

Comment: Using jQuery it's easy to make

Comment: Just search "single page app tutorial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manually zoom out you can see that they've literally just laid the page out that way. They use `overflow: hidden:` to make the page unscrollable, and then set the margins to be negative so that they can put things off of the page.

The primary thing they do, though, is use ids and the #id to then go to that part of the page.

Example:

`<div id="pizza"></div>`

You would then use `thispage.html#pizza` to focus on that part of the page.